# Center progress-value on progress-bar background

Tags: html, css, alignment, progress

I am using `progress` element on my page but I have an issue with its background since the background and the filled part are not center aligned.

Here is my progress

```
<progress className={'progress'} max="100" value={value}>
        {value}%
      </progress>
```

With the css

```
.progress {
    height: 10px
    background: #BABABA center;
    border-color: transparent;
    border-radius: 6px;
  }

  progress::-webkit-progress-bar {
    height: 10px;
    background-color: #BABABA;
    border-radius: 6px;
  }
  progress::-webkit-progress-value {
    height: 16px;
    background-color: #128CA2;
    border-radius: 6px;
  }
  progress::-moz-progress-bar {
    background-color: #128CA2;
    border-radius: 6px;
  }
```

How could I have the background and the filled part to be center aligned ?

[image: Not center aligned]

Comment: did you have any constraints in height of progress bar ?

Comment: `margin-top: -3px`? if you know the bar is 10px in height and the slider is going to be 16px then move it up? Also please can you make a [mcve] with your rendered html and css - what you have supplied does not look like your image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**New answer**

You can use `position: absolute;` on the progress-value and use `top: -3px;` to center it.

See comments in the snippet:

```css
.progress {
  height: 10px background: #BABABA center;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

progress::-webkit-progress-bar {
  position: relative; /* Added this */
  height: 10px;
  background-color: #BABABA;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

progress::-webkit-progress-value { /* Modified below */
  position: absolute;
  top: -3px;
  height: 16px;
  background-color: #128CA2;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

progress::-moz-progress-bar {
  background-color: #128CA2;
  border-radius: 6px;
}
```

```html
<progress class="progress" max="100" value="10"></progress>
```

---

**Old answer**

You can use a `linear-gradient` to visually reduce the colored-background height of the bar:

```css
.progress { /* Modified this */
  height: 16px;
  background: linear-gradient(transparent 20%, #BABABA 20%, #BABABA 80%, transparent 80%) center;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 16px;
}

progress::-webkit-progress-bar {
  height: 10px;
  background: transparent; /* Modified here */
  border-radius: 6px;
}

progress::-webkit-progress-value {
  height: 16px;
  background-color: #128CA2;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

progress::-moz-progress-bar {
  background-color: #128CA2;
  border-radius: 6px;
}
```

```html
<progress class="progress" max="100" value="10"></progress>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: The progress background has to be thinner than the colored part, that's why they are not center aligned

Comment: @Tibo I understand what you want now that your post has been edited. I'm updating mine soon. You should correct the missing `;` in your CSS, too.

Comment: Working but seems to be a little tricky, since the resulting border radius is not as smooth at it should be :s

Comment: @Tibo I am currently looking for a better way to do it. I'll notice you if I find something nice!

Comment: Anyway thank you for your help, if there is no other solution at least I have one :)

Answer (score 0):

To center align vertically, and horizontally use this technique :

```css
.selector {
position : absolute;
left : 50%;
top  :50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background : orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="selector">
  <div class="box a">A</div>
</div>
```

Hope, it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Added the margin-top in negative value to change the alignment

```css
.progress {
  height: 10px;
  background: #BABABA;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 6px;
  transform: translate( 0px, 8px);
}

progress::-webkit-progress-bar {
  height: 10px;
  background-color: #BABABA;
  border-radius: 6px;
  margin-top: -6px;
}

progress::-webkit-progress-value {
  height: 16px;
  background-color: #128CA2;
  border-radius: 6px;
  margin-top: -6px;
}

progress::-moz-progress-bar {
  background-color: #128CA2;
  border-radius: 6px;
  margin-top: -6px;
}
```

```html
<progress class='progress' max="100" value='20'>
    20%
 </progress>
```

Comment: The progress background has to be thinner than the colored background, that's why they are not center aligned

Comment: I added a picture to illustrate the current situation. The progress (colored in blue), has to be taller than the background (in grey)

Comment: @Tibo. I hope adding margin-top: -5px would help